# OpenGraph's Image field not working for Content Hub images

Tags: sxa, content-hub, dam

I have a fresh SXA instance with version 10.3. It is connected to a Content Hub.
In the default `Home` page, there is an `Image` field in the `Open Graph` section.

**Test with image from Media Library**

For the `Image` field, I selected an image from the Media Library and this is the raw value:

`<image mediaid="{25E5EAC8-BEA2-4C67-A248-F9F2F5435BAF}" />`

On browsing the Home page, the `og:image` property is rendered as expected.

`<meta property="og:image" content="https://sample.local/-/media/Project/Test.jpg" />`

**Test with image from Content Hub DAM**

Now, I selected an image from the DAM and the raw value is like this:

`<image stylelabs-content-id="45195" thumbnailsrc="https://example.sitecorecontenthub.cloud/api/gateway/45195/thumbnail" src="https://example-delivery.sitecorecontenthub.cloud/api/public/content/b7da722f683e4ee88eaa0e20bc3b7956?v=4ba95198" mediaid="" stylelabs-content-type="Image" alt="nature.jpg" height="502" width="1149" />`

The `og:image` property is rendered like this:

`<meta property="og:image" content="<image stylelabs-content-id=" 45195"="" thumbnailsrc="https://example.sitecorecontenthub.cloud/api/gateway/45195/thumbnail" src="https://example-delivery.sitecorecontenthub.cloud/api/public/content/b7da722f683e4ee88eaa0e20bc3b7956?v=4ba95198" mediaid="" stylelabs-content-type="Image" alt="nature-walk-keppel-bay-masthead1.jpg" height="502" width="1149">`

This metadata is rendered by the default SXA rendering - `/sitecore/layout/Renderings/Feature/Experience Accelerator/SiteMetadata/OpenGraphMetaData`

So, is this a bug?
Do we need to custom code to read DAM images. If yes, could you please share the logic.
Or is there any configuration setting to fix this.